# I have problems with screen resolution upscaling of my responsive web designs

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, materialize

I have made multiple personal projects for practising website designs and different JS frameworks. For the most part, I've learned how to do responsive design, whether with pure CSS media queries and flexbox, or with frameworks like Bootstrap and Materialize. However, I still haven't been able to figure out the screen resolution upscaling issues, and at this point, I don't know where to even start.

My work setup screen resolution is standard 1920x1080, but whenever I load my projects on monitors with higher res, none of the elements (text, images, SVGs) scale up in size, while sticking to their relative/absolute positions in layout, making the whole design fall apart or become disjointed. Same thing happens when I artificially change the resolution of the tab in Chrome with the dev tools.

My setup is pretty basic, I'm using VS Code, with a local node testing server in the background and Chrome. None of the documentation or tutorials have addressed this, so I don't know where to look for answers. Please help me...